# SQlite query for Distinct date in DateTime

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite, datetime

I have a table that store a DateTime value. In my query, i want to get the DISTINCT value base on Date only, meaning i want to get a single record per day ignoring the Time value.

GPSDATA table values

- 2016-08-25 21:23:42
- 2016-08-25 08:23:42
- 2016-08-25 06:53:42
- 2016-08-15 06:53:42
- 2016-06-15 06:53:43
- 2016-06-15 05:52:43
- 2016-06-07 05:56:43
- 2016-06-06 05:56:43
- 2016-06-05 05:56:43
- 2016-05-05 21:23:42

Upon executing this query, i still get all the records.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `rdatetime` FROM `gpsdata`
```

I need a query that gives me this result, Thank you in advance.

- 2016-08-25 21:23:42
- 2016-08-15 06:53:42
- 2016-06-15 06:53:43
- 2016-06-07 05:56:43
- 2016-06-06 05:56:43
- 2016-06-05 05:56:43
- 2016-05-05 21:23:42

Comment: I think you missed the 2016-06-06 and 2016-06-07 dates in the results. Or do you want to get the dates in 5 day intervals?

Comment: @brokenisfixed yes i missed, updated now, i want to get DISTINCT result base on dates only not 5 days intervals.

Comment: @Draeko: I can see 2 records for 2016-05-05, do you expect that in your result

Comment: @GauravLad i only have 1, its 2016-06-05 and 2016-05-05. kindly check it again.

Comment: @GauravLad thanks so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have SQL Server to test the query, but i believe this should work, please check on your side and let me know the result

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(rdatetime) FROM gpsdata
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Gaurav Lad, its perfectly working.